# How to set accept header in javascript with octokit API?

Tags: javascript, rest, github-api, octokit

I'm using octokit API to search some data in github. Howerver I have no idea about how to set accept headers. Here's the link:https://docs.github.com/en/rest/activity/starring. I want to set accept to "application/vnd.github+json".

Here's my code.

```
const octokit = new Octokit({
  auth: `...`,
  
  //Accept:"application/vnd.github+json",should I add it here?
});
const commitMessage = await octokit.request(
            "GET /repos/{owner}/{repo}/stargazers",
            {
                owner: owner,
                repo: name,
                per_page: 100,
                page: pageid,

            }
        );
```

Answer (score 3):

You can pass `headers` as another parameter to any request. However the `application/vnd.github+json` accept header is set for you by default